# Update client state received from api without refreshing in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I have two functions, one where I am able to send an order that updates the users balance amongst some other things, and another which retrieves the users balance for the user to see. Before any orders happen I still need to retrieve the balance for the user to see, thus I have broken my `getBalance` func from `MarketLongFunc`.

Using redux-toolkit and redux-thunk I have an `ordersSlice.js` that looks like this:

```
export const MarketLongFunc = createAsyncThunk(
  "/order/marketlong",
  async (value, thunkAPI) => {
    const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
    const newObj = {
      value: value,
      token: token,
    };

    let url = `http://localhost:3001/api/orders/marketlong`;
    const response = await axios.post(url, newObj);
    //getBalance() 
    return;
  }
);




export const getBalance = createAsyncThunk(
  "/order/getBalance",
  async (value, thunkAPI) => {
    const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
    const newObj = {
      token: token,
    };
    let url = `http://localhost:3001/api/orders/getBalance`;
    const response = await axios.post(url, newObj);
    return response.data;
  }
);

const initialState = {
  value: null,
  error: null,
  balance: null,
  status: "idle",
  orderStatus: "idle",
};
export const ordersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "orders",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
    resetStatus: (state) => {
        state.orderStatus = "idle";
    },
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(MarketLongFunc.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.orderStatus = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(MarketLongFunc.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.orderStatus = "success";
        // getBalance();
        // state.balance = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(MarketLongFunc.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.orderStatus = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      })
      .addCase(getBalance.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(getBalance.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        // state.status = "success";
        state.balance = action.payload;
        state.status = "success";
      })
      .addCase(getBalance.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      });
  },
});

export const { reset } = ordersSlice.actions;
export default ordersSlice.reducer;
```

Now in my next component the `useEffect` will call if there is no balance yet and the user is logged in. The way in which I was trying to solve my issue was to use the `state.orderStatus = "success"` under `MarketLongFunc.fulfilled`, this way hypothetically I can dispatch getbalance under the useEffect if a MarketLong is placed and then change the status with reset like the following:

```
export const Orderform = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);
  const balance = useSelector((state) => state.orders.balance);
  const status = useSelector((state) => state.orders.orderStatus);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!balance && user) {
      dispatch(getBalance());
    }

    if (status == "success") {
      dispatch(getBalance());
      dispatch(resetStatus());
    }
  }, [balance]);

  if (user) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          cash balance: ${balance ? Math.round(balance.balance) : "error"}
        </h1>
        <MarketLong />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      Login
    </div>
  );
};
```

The above code does not work currently as when I `console.log(status)` on refresh is is `idle` and when I use marketLong it is `loading` but it never makes it to fulfilled so still the only way to update the balance that is displayed after an order is to refresh the page. I want to update the displayed balance without refreshing the page as refreshing the page will have to make two other API calls on top of the `getBalance`. I have left some comments in where I tried things like just putting the `getBalance` function inside the `MarketLongFunc` in the ordersSlice, I also tried returning it etc but that did nothing and I figured fixing this issue in the useEffect with the status' would be the best way to fix this but I am open to hearing other solutions besides creating redundant code where I just basically type out the getBalance func inside marketLongFunc.

Another way that almost works is just adding `dispatch(getBalance())` after `dispatch(MarketLongFunc(longItem));` in my `MarketLong` react component like the following:

```
  const addNewLong = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const longItem = {
      userInput: req.ticker,
      quotePrice: req.quotePrice,
      quantity: Item.quantity,
    };

    dispatch(MarketLongFunc(longItem));
    dispatch(getBalance());

  };
```

The problem with this is the first order never gets updated but after that it updates incorrectly as the balance will be off by one buy order. I imagine this is due to getBalance gettting called before MarketLongFunc but without setting a manual `setTimeout` func which seems like a clunky solution, I am not sure how to fix that with redux, you would think something like : `if (dispatch(MarketLongFunc(longItem))) {dispatch(getBalance())}`, but maybe this way needs to be changed in the ordersSlice (which I had tried and was not able to get it to work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem - I will describe an approximate solution:

```js
export const MarketLongFunc = createAsyncThunk(
  "/order/marketlong",
  async (value, thunkAPI) => {
    const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
    const newObj = {
      value: value,
      token: token,
    };

    let url = `http://localhost:3001/api/orders/marketlong`;
    const response = await axios.post(url, newObj);
    //getBalance() 
    return;
  }
);




export const getBalance = createAsyncThunk(
  "/order/getBalance",
  async (value, thunkAPI) => {
    const token = thunkAPI.getState().auth.user.token;
    const newObj = {
      token: token,
    };
    let url = `http://localhost:3001/api/orders/getBalance`;
    const response = await axios.post(url, newObj);
    return response.data;
  }
);

const initialState = {
  value: null,
  error: null,
  balance: null,
  status: "idle",
  orderStatus: "idle",
  balanceNeedsToBeUpdated: true // <--- HERE
};
export const ordersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "orders",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: (state) => initialState,
  },
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(MarketLongFunc.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.orderStatus = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(MarketLongFunc.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.orderStatus = "idle";
        state.balanceNeedsToBeUpdated = true; // < ----- HERE
        // getBalance();
        // state.balance = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(MarketLongFunc.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.orderStatus = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      })
      .addCase(getBalance.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(getBalance.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        // state.status = "success";
        state.balance = action.payload;
        state.status = "idle";
        state.balanceNeedsToBeUpdated = false; // <---- HERE
      })
      .addCase(getBalance.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      });
  },
});

export const { reset } = ordersSlice.actions;
export default ordersSlice.reducer;

export const Orderform = () => {
  const user = useSelector((state) => state.auth.user);
  const balance = useSelector((state) => state.orders.balance);
  const status = useSelector((state) => state.orders.status);
  const orderStatus = useSelector((state) => state.orders.orderStatus);
  const balanceNeedsToBeUpdated = useSelector((state) => state.orders.balanceNeedsToBeUpdated);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();


  useEffect(() => {
    if (user && balanceNeedsToBeUpdated) { //< ----- HERE
      dispatch(getBalance());
    }
  }, [user, balanceNeedsToBeUpdated]); // < ---- HERE

  if (user) {
    if (status == 'loading' || orderStatus == 'loading') {
      return <div>loading</div>;
    }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>
          cash balance: ${balance ? Math.round(balance.balance) : "error"}
        </h1>
        <MarketLong />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <div>
      Login
    </div>
  );
};

//....

  const addNewLong = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const longItem = {
      userInput: req.ticker,
      quotePrice: req.quotePrice,
      quantity: Item.quantity,
    };

    dispatch(MarketLongFunc(longItem)); // < --- HERE
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, I did find out last night the way I was trying to solve this in `if (status == 'success')` works so long as I actually return something from the backend, since I was not sending any JSON to the frontend I could never get the status to equal success. I might do a separate post with how I solved this but your answer is good also and I will accept it so you get the credit.